# To Write a C Program to take 32 bit integer and display Higher and lower words (16-bits) using union

Tags: c, embedded

```
union breakbit {
    int32_t data;
    int16_t low;
    int16_t high;
} var;

int main() {
    var.data = 0x12345678;
    printf("Initial value:%x\n",var.data);
    printf("Higher bit value:%x\n",var.uplow.high);
    printf("Higher bit value:%x\n",var.uplow.low);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is only lower bits and not higher, so anyone can help finding the higher bits value?

Comment: Note: While what you want to do will very probably work (if you do it right, as per the other answers), there is no guarantee it will: The compiler is allowed to liberally move around union members mostly at will - There is no guarantee in the standard that the members are overlaid in the order you define them. So, this is entirely non-portable.

Comment: @tofro Do you think `union breakbit { uint32_t data32; uint16_t data16[2]; };` risks being unexpectantly overlaid?  IMO, it is well defined.

Comment: @chux It is *reasonable* to assume the two 16-bit values sit on top of the 32-bit value, yes, and in very many cases it will actually work as intended. The standard doesn't promise it, though. A compiler could overlay the union in some sort of shifted way, or even not at all, and then there is the small problem of endianess. The standard explicitly says *It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written*. Using unions to split longer data types into their components is the most non-portable way of doing that.

Comment: @tofro, "The standard explicitly says It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written" sound like C++ and does not apply to C. Perhaps cite a C reference? "compiler could overlay the union in some sort of shifted way" --> Not in this case as both union members are the initial ones. Padding specified to not happen before the first member. Size of `uint32_t` always the same size as `uint16_t[2]`.  Endian remains a issue yet big/little is sorted out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441982/2410359).

Answer (score 2):

In your example, all three `data`, `low` and `high` overlay one-another.

As per your printf statement, declare the union so:

```
union breakbit {
    uint32_t data;
    struct {
        uint16_t low;
        uint16_t high;
    } uplow;
} var;
```

The meaning of 'low' and 'high` will be different on different machines. (See "Big Endian/Little Endian")

EDIT: When dealing with hex values, you probably want to use an `unsigned` datatype. I've altered this example to conform.

Comment: Better yet drop the struct name (anonymous struct as per C11 or later) and then you can refer to the struct members by typing `var.high` instead of `var.uplow.high`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, if your compiler is up to date. The OP seemed focussed on the union declaration, and I didn't want to go into changing the printf parameters... Thanks for the addendum :-)

Answer (score 2):

To addition to [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73440301/2410359) good answer and untangle the endian:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union breakbit {
  uint32_t data32;
  uint16_t data16[2];
};

// Using a C99 compound literal to index the LS half.
#define LS_INDEX ((const union breakbit){ .data32 = 1}.data16[1])

int main(void) {
  union breakbit var = {.data32 = rand() * (RAND_MAX + 1ul) + rand()};
  printf("Initial value:%08lx\n", (unsigned long) var.data32);

  printf("Higher bits value:%04x\n", var.data16[!LS_INDEX]);
  printf(" Lower bits value:%04x\n", var.data16[LS_INDEX]);
}
```

Output:

```
Initial value:c0b18ccf
Higher bits value:c0b1
 Lower bits value:8ccf
```